# Added the Google Chrome Extension and how to select the button "Add Extension" in the confirmation pop up?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I added the Google Chrome Extension. How do I select the button "Add Extension" in the confirmation pop up?

I do the following steps. Note that they are automated in `Selenium Webdriver` using Java:

1. In browser, loaded the Google Chrome Webstore Extension URL, e.g. [Gmail Offline](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-offline/ejidjjhkpiempkbhmpbfngldlkglhimk)
2. Click the button "Add to Chrome" and it is checking.
3. Google chrome displays "Confirmation pop up".
4. In the Confirmation pop up, how to select the "Add Extension" button ?

[Here is a screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PufaU.jpg). Could you please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to automate the addition process? Google already pay people to do that. Are you just trying to ensure your tests run with the extension installed?

Comment: In my project, i need to install an extension from the Google Webstore. So I am trying to do that.

Comment: yes, but you don't have to go to Chrome Store each time. You can tell ChromeDriver to load an extension from a file for each run.

Comment: Can I help you with that?